# Layout in Blackberry

Tags: java, layout, blackberry, user-interface

I'm new to blackberry development. Is there something like palette as android in blackberry for creating layout?
Or any other best approch to create layout in blackberry?

Comment: By *palette*, do you mean the **Layout Editor** in Eclipse, that you can use to build your layouts, without writing code?

Comment: @Nate-yep for the blackberry.

Comment: For those not familiar with the Eclipse plugin for Android development, the poster is asking about [something like this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#graphical-editor), (ideally) not which classes in the BlackBerry UI framework handle layout.

Comment: There is nothing like that for blackberry AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

In Blackberry 
There are managers to do this work of layout

Answer (score 1):

> @user1928849 - Can you please tell me how can we connect or attach the
>   lwuit created file with our blackberry project?

Check this link out for netbeans hope it helps

[Generating A Netbeans Project From The Resource Editor from CodeNameOne Blog](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/2009/02/22/lwuit-demo-on-blackberry-with-eclipse.html)

And for eclipse -

[LWUIT Demo on BlackBerry with Eclipse](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/2009/02/22/lwuit-demo-on-blackberry-with-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 0):

In Blackberry there are `Layout Managers` for creating `UserInterface`.

There are really just 4 built in layout managers.
These are the four main layout in blackberry

- VerticalFieldManager – this layout manager simply lays out the fields you add to it, from top/bottom.
- HorizontalFieldManager – this layout manager simply lays out the fields you add to it, from left to right, on one row.
- FlowFieldManager – this layout manager simply adds fields you add from left to right, and adds as many to one row as possible, before starting a new row, and just keeps adding rows as needed.
- DialogFieldManager – this layout manager allows you to layout fields in a fixed template, which has an icon and message on the top row, followed by a set of fields you can add underneath it.

You can use this tutorial to understand the working of layout in `Blackberry` [Working with BlackBerry Layout Managers – Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=808) for further reading see this tutorial too.[User Interface in BlackBerry](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/manish1231/working-with-layout-managers-user-interface-in-blackberry/). And please look at the [Manager doc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html).